# instagram and facebook videos not downloading using flutter_downloader

Tags: flutter, dart, download, flutter-dependencies, flutter-downloader

I am making a Flutter video download manager. I am using [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) plugin. But the problem being faced is that either video is not downloading or it is not playing if downloaded. Below is the code to download the video from Facebook and Instagram.

```
Future<void> _startDownload() async {
    final url = _urlController.text.trim();
    if (url.isEmpty) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Empty URL'),
          content: const Text('Please enter a video URL.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      return;
    } else if (!isValidVideoUrl(url)) {
      // Show an error message or handle the invalid URL case
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Invalid URL'),
          content: const Text('Please enter a valid video URL.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      return;
    } else {
      TaskInfo task = TaskInfo(url: url);
      await _requestDownload(task);
      setState(() {
        _tasks!.add(task);
        _items!.add(ItemHolder(name: task.name, task: task));
      });
    }
  }
bool isValidVideoUrl(String url) {
    final Uri? uri = Uri.tryParse(url);

    if (uri == null) {
      // Invalid URL format
      return false;
    }

    // Check if the URL scheme is HTTP or HTTPS
    if (uri.scheme != 'http' && uri.scheme != 'https') {
      return false;
    }

    // Check if the URL host belongs to a valid video hosting platform
    final String host = uri.host.toLowerCase();
    if (host.contains('www.instagram.com') ||
        host.contains('www.tiktok.com') ||
        host.contains('www.reels.com') ||
        host.contains('www.facebook.com')) {
      return true;
    }

    //Invalid video URL
    return false;
  }
```

parsing URI

```
 Future<void> _requestDownload(TaskInfo task) async {
    final url = task.url!;
    if (_permissionReady) {
      final fileName = '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4';

      final response = await Dio().head(url);
      final contentType = response.headers['content-type']?.toString();
      final fileExtension = _getFileExtension(contentType);

      task.taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
        url: url,
        savedDir: _localPath!,
        fileName: '$fileName$fileExtension',
        saveInPublicStorage: _saveInPublicStorage,
        showNotification: true,
        openFileFromNotification: true,
      );
    }
  }

  String _getFileExtension(String? contentType) {
    if (contentType != null) {
      if (contentType.contains('video/mp4')) {
        return '.mp4';
      } else if (contentType.contains('video/3gpp')) {
        return '.3gp';
      } else if (contentType.contains('video/mpeg')) {
        return '.mpg';
      }
      // Add more cases for other content types and their corresponding file extensions
    }
    return '.mp4'; // Default to '.mp4' if the content type is unknown
  }
```

I want to download the file in proper format and the video must play after download.

Answer (score -1):

You can't download videos from FB or Instagram by sharing URL, you must get a real path to download

Comment: how to get the real path of FB and Instagram videos?